# Is there an efficient way to compare each key, value pair of a dictionary in a many to one comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query

Idea is to compare N number of dictionaries with a single standard dictionary where each key, value pair comparison has a different conditional rule.

Eg.,

Standard dictionary -

```
{'ram': 16,
  'storage': [512, 1, 2],
  'manufacturers': ['Dell', 'Apple', 'Asus', 'Alienware'],
  'year': 2018,
  'drives': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
}
```

List of dictionaries -

```
{'ram': 8,
  'storage': 1,
  'manufacturers': 'Apple',
  'year': 2018,
  'drives': ['C', 'D', 'E']
},
{'ram': 16,
  'storage': 4,
  'manufacturers': 'Asus',
  'year': 2021,
  'drives': ['F', 'G','H']
}, 
{'ram': 4,
  'storage': 2,
  'manufacturers': 'ACER',
  'year': 2016,
  'drives': ['F', 'G', 'H']
}
```

Conditions-

1. 'ram' > 8
2. if 'ram' >=8 then 'storage' >= 2 else 1
3. 'manufactures' in ['Dell', 'Apple', 'Asus', 'Alienware']
4. 'year' >= 2018
5. if 'year' > 2018 then 'drives' in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']  else ['F', 'G', 'H']

So the expected output is to display all the non-matching ones with non-matching values and none/null for the matching values.

Expected Output -

```
{'ram': 8,
  'storage': 1,
  'manufacturers': None,
  'year': None,
  'drives': ['C', 'D', 'E']
},
{'ram': None,
  'storage': None,
  'manufacturers': None,
  'year': None,
  'drives': ['F','G','H']
}, 
{'ram': 4,
  'storage': 2,
  'manufacturers': 'ACER',
  'year': 2016,
  'drives': None
}
```

While working with MongoDB I encountered this problem where each document in a data collection should be compared with a standard collection. Any MongoDB direct query would also be very helpful.

Comment: Please share the MongoDB sample document in question in addition to dictionaries. What you are looking for is possible using MongoDB Aggregation.

Comment: @hhharsha36 It's a big collection with 40 key-value pairs and based on the condition I need to compare the standard collection with that of the data collection. Above example is glimpse what is to be expected. Due to privacy issues, I can't share the exact collection.

Comment: So you just want to compare the standard collection with another different collection where the values (dictionaries in this case) are stored in an array, based on the conditions parsed from the standard collection record. Right?

Comment: Mostly yes but with a slight difference. Yes, there's standard collection and a different collection with say 1000 records (each being a dictionary of course) and now I need to compare each of the fields with the same field in the standard collection. FYR, it's just like having multiple users data of Aadhar form, and you want to highlight the differences from that of a standard Aadhar form template that you've defined. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the conditions along using MongoDB Aggregation, use the below Query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "ram": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              "$ram",
              8
            ]
          },
          "then": null,
          "else": "$ram",
        }
      },
      "storage": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$ram",
                  8
                ]
              },
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$storage",
                  2
                ]
              },
              
            ],
          },
          "then": null,
          "else": "$storage",
        }
      },
      "manufacturers": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$in": [
              "$manufacturers",
              [
                "Dell",
                "Apple",
                "Asus",
                "Alienware"
              ], 
            ]
          },
          "then": null,
          "else": "$manufacturers",
        }
      },
      "year": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gte": [
              "$year",
              2018
            ]
          },
          "then": null,
          "else": "$year",
        }
      },
      "drives": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              "$year",
              2018
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$drives",
              [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "else": "$drives",
        }
      },
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O6b2XyTaqxH)

You can combine this with for loop in Python

```
for std_doc in std_col.find({}, {
  "ram": 1,
  "storage": 1,
  "manufacturers": 1,
  "year": 1,
  "drives": 1,
}):
  print(list(list_col.aggregate([
    {
    "$project": {
      "ram": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              "$ram",
              8
            ]
          },
          "then": None,
          "else": "$ram",
        }
      },
      "storage": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$ram",
                  8
                ]
              },
              {
                "$gte": [
                  "$storage",
                  2
                ]
              },
              
            ],
          },
          "then": None,
          "else": "$storage",
        }
      },
      "manufacturers": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$in": [
              "$manufacturers",
              [
                "Dell",
                "Apple",
                "Asus",
                "Alienware"
              ], 
            ]
          },
          "then": None,
          "else": "$manufacturers",
        }
      },
      "year": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gte": [
              "$year",
              2018
            ]
          },
          "then": None,
          "else": "$year",
        }
      },
      "drives": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$gt": [
              "$year",
              2018
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$drives",
              [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "else": "$drives",
        }
      },
    }
  }
])))
```

The most optimized solution is to perform a lookup, but this varies based on your requirement:

```
db.std_col.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "dict_col",
      "let": {
        "cmpRam": "$ram",
        "cmpStorage": "$storage",
        "cmpManufacturers": "$manufacturers",
        "cmpYear": "$year",
        "cmpDrives": "$drives",
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "ram": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  "$gt": [
                    "$ram",
                    "$$cmpRam",
                  ]
                },
                "then": null,
                "else": "$ram",
              }
            },
            "storage": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      "$gte": [
                        "$ram",
                        "$$cmpRam"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$gte": [
                        "$storage",
                        "$$cmpStorage"
                      ]
                    },
                  ],
                },
                "then": null,
                "else": "$storage",
              }
            },
            "manufacturers": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  "$in": [
                    "$manufacturers",
                    "$$cmpManufacturers",
                  ]
                },
                "then": null,
                "else": "$manufacturers",
              }
            },
            "year": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  "$gte": [
                    "$year",
                    "$$cmpYear",
                  ]
                },
                "then": null,
                "else": "$year",
              }
            },
            "drives": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": {
                  "$gt": [
                    "$year",
                    "$$cmpYear"
                  ]
                },
                "then": {
                  "$setIntersection": [
                    "$drives",
                    "$$cmpDrives"
                  ]
                },
                "else": "$drives",
              }
            },
          }
        },
      ],
      "as": "inventory_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HgQ2Pw4EwsK)